# Debian 9 mixes up network adapters

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, debian, ip

I have two `server` systems, one running `Debian Stretch`, the other `Ubuntu 17.10`, both of which have two network adapters, configured in the following way (`/etc/network/interfaces`):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.2.x
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.2.0
        broadcast 192.168.2.255
        gateway 192.168.2.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Also, initial ram disks on both systems have the same IP addresses (yes, I an using the "old school" interface names) configured with (`/etc/default/grub`):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ip=192.168.2.x::192.168.2.1:255.255.255.0:whatever:eth0:off"
```

On both systems, the first adapter is always connected to the local network, and the second one is almost never connected to anything, but occasionally used for testing network equipment.

What sometimes (1/10 times) happens is, after reboot, the adapter names switch places, and all of a sudden `eth1` has a `MAC` address that `eth0` had before reboot, and has a `DHCP` obtained address. This happens in the initial ram disk as well.

Now, `Debian Jesse` and `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` both had `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` which clearly stated which `MAC` belongs to which interface name. This file does not exist on my systems, I never removed a single package nor deleted that file from those two systems. I tried recreating the file with:

```
udevadm trigger --type=devices --action=change
udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=net --action=add
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

And after reboot, the file is not present, and adapters still sometimes switch places. Any hint or idea how to fix this annoying issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to copy the old files to the new systems? `udev` is `udev`, it should still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network interfaces are probed at boot and the result of this probing is not predictable. The interface names are assigned in the order they are found, but unfortunately this is not determistic. This is exactly the problem with the "old school" interface names that [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) is attempting to solve.

You can also create a udev rule file "by hand" to map a MAC address to an interface name, for example:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-network.rules

SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff", NAME="net1"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="ff:ee:dd:cc:bb:aa", NAME="net0"
```

Note that it is not the MAC addresses that are swapped, but the interface names. The MAC address is (usually) fixed on the hardware. What's happening in your case is that the physical interface that has the name "eth0" sometimes gets the name "eth1", which means your static network configuration is applied to the wrong port.

Comment: I was about to test that, but will it work in initramfs as well? I need the proper IP there as well.

Comment: It will work in initramfs, or it can be made to work there. Depends on the initramfs. The problem I see with adding this to initramfs is that editing the initramfs is tricky, and you edits will be overwritten the next time the initramfs is updated. Some aspects of the initramfs can be configured in `initramfs.conf`, but I don't see any variables that would affect the contents of the -network.rules file. If I were you, I would bite the bullet and migrate to predictable network interface names.

Comment: I bit the bullet and now the network interface names are bulletproof! I tested it, works 15/15 times. Thank you!